# same activity shown after few seconds interval

Tags: android

I have developed an Android app ,Which has splash screens once the slider completes the MainActivity is shown but In my case once the MainActivity is shown it gets automatically reloads (open like when the MainActivity open first time)after few seconds(approximately 5 sec).

This is my SplashScreenActivity

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private LinearLayout dots_layout;
    private TextView[] dots_count;
    private int[] layouts;
    private Button button_next;
    private Button button_skip;
    private SplashScreenAdapter splashScreenAdapter;
    private SharedPreference sharedPreference;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        sharedPreference = new SharedPreference(this);
        if (!sharedPreference.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
            startFunctionsActivity();
            finish();
        }else{
            sharedPreference.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
        }
        setStatusbarTransparent();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        dots_layout =(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.splashscreen_dots);
        button_next =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_next);
        button_skip =(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_skip);

        button_next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int currentpage = viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1;
                if (currentpage < layouts.length) {
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(currentpage);
                } else {
                    startFunctionsActivity();
                }
            }
        });
        button_skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
            startFunctionsActivity();
            }
        });

        layouts = new int[]{R.layout.slider_one,R.layout.slider_two,R.layout.slider_three,R.layout.slider_four};
        splashScreenAdapter = new SplashScreenAdapter(layouts,getApplicationContext());
        viewPager.setAdapter(splashScreenAdapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
                    button_next.setText("START");
                    button_skip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    button_next.setText("NEXT");
                    button_skip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                setDotStatus(position);
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });
        setDotStatus(0);

    }
    private void setDotStatus(int page) {
        dots_layout.removeAllViews();
        dots_count = new TextView[layouts.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < dots_count.length; i++) {
            dots_count[i] = new TextView(this);
            dots_count[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots_count[i].setTextSize(30);
            dots_count[i].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#a9b4bb"));
            dots_layout.addView(dots_count[i]);
        }
        if (dots_count.length > 0) {
            dots_count[page].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        }
    }
    private void startFunctionsActivity() {
        sharedPreference.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, FunctionsActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    private void setStatusbarTransparent() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }
}
```

SplashScreenAdapter

```
public class SplashScreenAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int[] layouts;
    private Context context;

    public SplashScreenAdapter(int[] layouts, Context context) {
        this.layouts = layouts;
        this.context = context;
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view==object;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View V = inflater.inflate(layouts[position],container,false);
        container.addView(V);
        return V;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View) object);
        View v =(View)object;
        container.removeView(v);
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textview_myQuote;
    private ImageView imageView_logo;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        if (!isFirstTimeStartApp()) {
            startSplashScreenActivity();
            finish();
        }else{
            setFirstTimeStartStatus(false);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textview_myQuote = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen_text);
        imageView_logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splash_screen_logo);

        Animation animation = (Animation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.welcomescreen_animation);
        textview_myQuote.startAnimation((Animation) animation);
        imageView_logo.startAnimation((Animation) animation);

        final  Intent intent = new Intent(this,SplashScreenActivity.class);

         /* Purpose : splash screen animation on logo and Textview */

        Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                finally {
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        };
        timerThread.start();
    }
    private boolean isFirstTimeStartApp() {
        SharedPreferences ref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("splashscreen", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return ref.getBoolean("Flag", true);
    }

    private void setFirstTimeStartStatus(boolean status) {
        SharedPreferences ref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("splashscreen", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = ref.edit();
        editor.putBoolean("Flag", status);
        editor.commit();
    }
    private void startSplashScreenActivity() {
        setFirstTimeStartStatus(false);
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SplashScreenActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

from this activity only I called the FunctionsActivity (MainActivity).But it reloads after few seconds.Please guide me to solve it.

Comment: Is this happening 1st launch also?

Comment: Yes,every time it happens

Comment: can you add `SplashScreenAdapter` code?

Comment: okay wait a minute

Comment: I dont know why its happening for 1st launch. I can tell you about  2ed lunch case. When you are calling `finish()` the activity desen't terminate `onCreate()`. So all code like setting ViewPager and button will still run. May be something in viewpager setup bringing activity back. Can you try to put all this code in else part or `if(!sharedPreference.isFirstTimeLaunch())`

Comment: Nothing is worked,confused ..!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167369/discussion-between-vishu-and-nikson).

Comment: okay,sure.......

Answer (score 0):

you finished Splash Activity twice...

```
if (!sharedPreference.isFirstTimeLaunch()) { startFunctionsActivity(); return;}
```

itz enough i think

Comment: did you removed finish in that condition

Comment: set Intent.setFlags(Intent FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
when start Functions Activity

Comment: added my mainactivity

Comment: when my slide show completed the FunctionsActivity is gets called once it shown on screen after 5 sec it shows again

Comment: use Handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){...}, 5000};

Comment: u also used finish twice in your main activity